# Black screen for video when testing on iOS simulator

Tags: react-native

I am trying to show a video using the [react-native-video](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-video) plugin. When testing on the device the video is working but on the iOS simulator it's showing black screen (Testing on simulator is faster and easy for me). Someone having the same issue. Here is my code:

```
                  <Video
                    source={{ uri: 'url' }}   // Can be a URL or a local file.
                    ref={(ref) => { this.player = ref; }}                             // Store reference
                    rate={1.0}                     // 0 is paused, 1 is normal.
                    volume={1.0}                   // 0 is muted, 1 is normal.
                    muted={false}                  // Mutes the audio entirely.
                    paused={this.state.paused}                 // Pauses playback entirely.
                    resizeMode="cover"             // Fill the whole screen at aspect ratio.
                    repeat={false}                // Repeat forever.
                    playInBackground={false}       // Audio continues to play when app entering background.
                    playWhenInactive={false}       // [iOS] Video continues to play when control or notification center are shown.
                    progressUpdateInterval={250.0} // [iOS] Interval to fire onProgress (default to ~250ms)
                    onLoadStart={this.loadStart}   // Callback when video starts to load
                    onLoad={this.setDuration}      // Callback when video loads
                    onProgress={this.setTime}      // Callback every ~250ms with currentTime
                    onEnd={this.onEnd}             // Callback when playback finishes
                    onError={this.videoError}      // Callback when video cannot be loaded
                    onBuffer={this.onBuffer} // Callback when remote video is buffering
                    style={styles.backgroundVideo}
                />
```

Answer (score 2):

> Simulator is designed to assist you in designing, rapidly prototyping, and testing your app, but it should never serve as your sole platform for testing. One reason is that not all apps are available in the simulator. For example, the Camera app is available only on hardware devices and cannot be replicated in the simulator.

The simulator won't use your computer's camera, so anytime you are using the camera for anything, it will just default to a black screen.

More Info: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/iOS_Simulator_Guide/GettingStartedwithiOSSimulator/GettingStartedwithiOSSimulator.html

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine but you can't play the video in any simulator, you need run the app in real device either android or ios.